# how to get typeorm manytomany relation column count

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

### User Entity

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => Product)
  @JoinTable()
  likedProducts: Product[]
}
```

### Product Entity

```
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()[enter image description here][1]
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => User)
  likedUsers: User[];
}
```

I would like to know the number of users who like certain products of Product Entity.

### Table Image Example

[TableImageExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8u41.png)

I want to get the number of columns with productId of 10.
Under circumstances, you cannot move JoinTable.

### I Tried

```
      const product = await this.products.findOne(id, {
        relations: ['likedUsers'],
      });
      console.log(product.likedUsers.length);
```

#### result

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tablePath' of undefined
    at /Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1539:76
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.createJoinExpression (/Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1498:57)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.getQuery (/Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:58:21)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.QueryBuilder.getQueryAndParameters (/Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts:440:28)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:2092:40)
    at step (/Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/project/monster-backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: i think you need to tell typeorm the "relation property" in the `ManyToMany` decorator. like this `@ManyToMany(type => Product, product => product.likedUsers)`. same in the products entity

Comment: glad to help :) i posted this as an answer. please mark it as correct answer for other people who will encounter a similar problem to have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to tell typeorm the "relation property" in the ManyToMany decorator. like this: `@ManyToMany(type => Product, product => product.likedUsers)`

same in the products entity.

you can read more about it in [the documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations#bi-directional-relations)